# In Visual Studio change my main project from Console to Window when I switch from Debug to Release

Tags: visual-studio

anyone knows how to do this automatically/programmatically? I mean, when I switch my solution from Debug to Release, I want my main project to change from Console to Window automatically.
I thought to use vb script, but I want to know if anyone has a better solution before.

Answer (score 1):

Console/Windowed subsystem is a per-project per-configuration setting. You can change it separately for Debug & Release configurations via project properties dialog - so you can just setup your Debug/Release configurations once (the settings are stored in the project files).

Comment: I don't really understand you. How can I link the Debug/Release change with the Consol/Window change ? I don't want to do the Consol/Window change manually.

Comment: The Debug/Release configuration doesn't store the configuration type (Console or Windows).